# Why PetaPoco is not adding parameters to my query

Tags: c#, sql, database, orm, petapoco

I'm facing a problem in PetaPoco, and I can't figure it out.

I'm using this code :

```
var db = new OracleConnection(_connectionString);

var query = Sql.Builder;
query.Append("SELECT * FROM City WHERE ID = @0", 1);

return db.Query<City>(query.SQL).ToList();
```

PetaPoco is not adding the parameter to my sql query.

[image: PetaPoco]

This is an example from their [official website](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/) :

```
var id=123;
var sql=PetaPoco.Sql.Builder
          .Append("SELECT * FROM articles")
          .Append("WHERE article_id=@0", id);
```

**For you information** : I'm using the last version of PetaPoco (5.0.1)

Answer (score 2):

I'd skip `Sql.Builder` (it's gaining you nothing here), and as a side-note, use `db.Fetch` as it already returns a `List`. So:

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM City WHERE ID = @0";
return db.Fetch<City>(query, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just `query` to the `Query<>` method, not just the sql.
Otherwise you need to pass the Arguments as the second parameter.